# How to use using directive with static type

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

In the example at MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx#Anchor_0), it explains how to use the using directive with static types.

However, when I try to imitate the example with the following code, I get an error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    // intellisense syntax errors show up in this line
    using static System.Console;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of visual studio/compiler?

Comment: @DanielA.White I think I see what you're getting at.

Comment: it works great for me on .net 4.5 vs2015

Comment: The `using` statement should be outside of the `namespace` declaration

Comment: @mrtig: No, it's fine in either place. (That's a using *directive*, btw. A using *statement* is what you use for resources, to dispose them automatically.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not supported in Visual Studio 2013 or C# 5.0. It is a C# 6.0 feature.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Gotta watch my versions.